# Error during the upgrade of LibreOffice from 6.3.5 to 6.4.2

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

On **Ubuntu MATE 18.04** (Bionic Beaver) I use the following PPA for LibreOffice:

```
$ inxi -r | grep libreoffice
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

Today I tried to upgrade LibreOffice from 6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 to 6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 and the upgrade finished with an error:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  uno-libs3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjuh-java libjurt-java libridl-java libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoil-java libunoloader-java uno-libs-private
The following packages will be upgraded:
  fonts-opensymbol libasound2 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-hr libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver
  libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-report-builder libreoffice-report-builder-bin
  libreoffice-script-provider-bsh libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-human
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer ure wire-desktop
41 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 170 MB of archives.
After this operation, 7,916 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...
Fetched 170 MB in 4min 42s (603 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 395606 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libreoffice-style-tango_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-tango (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-ure_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ure (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of libreoffice-common, which would be broken by installation of libreoffice-calc ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure libreoffice-common (broken by libreoffice-calc)
Preparing to unpack .../03-libreoffice-calc_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Unpacking libreoffice-calc (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libreoffice-gnome_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gnome (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libreoffice-gtk3_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gtk3 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libreoffice-impress_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-impress (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libreoffice-writer_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-writer (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of libreoffice-core, which would be broken by installation of libreoffice-draw ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure libreoffice-core (broken by libreoffice-draw)
Preparing to unpack .../08-libreoffice-draw_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libreoffice-core (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Unpacking libreoffice-draw (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-core (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of libreoffice-base, which would be broken by installation of libreoffice-core ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure libreoffice-base (broken by libreoffice-core)
Preparing to unpack .../09-libreoffice-core_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libreoffice-base (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Unpacking libreoffice-core (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0hnhY0/10-libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Application.xba', which is also in package libreoffice-base 1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of libreoffice-common, which would be broken by installation of libreoffice-base ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure libreoffice-common (broken by libreoffice-base)
Preparing to unpack .../11-libreoffice-base_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/dialog.xlc to /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/dialog.xlc.noaccess by libreoffice-base'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc to /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc.noaccess by libreoffice-base'
Unpacking libreoffice-base (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libreoffice-style-elementary_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-elementary (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libreoffice-style-colibre_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-colibre (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-libreoffice-script-provider-js_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-script-provider-js (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-libreoffice-script-provider-bsh_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-script-provider-bsh (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libreoffice-report-builder_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-report-builder (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Replacing files in old package libreoffice-common (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libreoffice-pdfimport_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-pdfimport (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libreoffice-ogltrans_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-ogltrans (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../19-libreoffice-l10n-hr_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-l10n-hr (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-libreoffice-l10n-en-za_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-l10n-en-za (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-libreoffice-l10n-en-gb_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-l10n-en-gb (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../22-libreoffice-java-common_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-java-common (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../23-libreoffice-help-en-us_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-help-en-us (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../24-libreoffice-help-en-gb_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-help-en-gb (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../25-libreoffice-help-common_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-help-common (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-libreoffice-base-drivers_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base-drivers (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../27-libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../28-libreoffice-base-core_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base-core (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../29-libreoffice-report-builder-bin_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-report-builder-bin (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../30-libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../31-libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-math (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0hnhY0/31-libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/modules/smath/menubar/menubar.xml', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Restoring backup of /usr/share/doc/libreoffice-math ...
Preparing to unpack .../32-libreoffice-sdbc-firebird_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-sdbc-firebird (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0hnhY0/10-libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0hnhY0/31-libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjuh-java libjurt-java libreoffice-common libreoffice-math libridl-java libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3
  libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoil-java libunoloader-java uno-libs-private
Recommended packages:
  python3-uno
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  uno-libs3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjuh-java libjurt-java libridl-java libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoil-java libunoloader-java uno-libs-private
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-math
2 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
32 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/29.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 32.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 395748 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-math (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/modules/smath/menubar/menubar.xml', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Restoring backup of /usr/share/doc/libreoffice-math ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 24):

Just ran into this same problem on the latest KDE Neon. I'm sure the broken package will be fixed shortly by the LibreOffice Fresh team, but in the meantime I managed to fix it using the following command:

`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb`

- The key here is the `--force-overwrite` option to dpkg, which addresses the error trying to overwrite `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/modules/smath/menubar/menubar.xml`, which is also in `libreoffice-common 1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1` package from the original package manager output.

After running this command, I then ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install` again to fix all the broken packages left behind by the incomplete LibreOffice install, and this time it actually went through and cleaned up everything properly.

Am now back to work in LibreOffice so I can confirm that this works (at least on this system)!

Comment: Thank you--this seems to have worked for me too! (Linux Mint 19.3 XFCE, also using the LO ppa.)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me in KDE-NEON. Saved my day :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked on kubuntu 18.04 !

Comment: Thanks Man!!! You saved my day! :-)
BTW: It works also on Ubuntu Mate 18.04(.04).

Answer (score 2):

I get exactly the same here on Linux Mint 19.3

Try the following to solve it:

- Start [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) and find broken packages
- Select them and remove
- Close Synaptic
- Open a terminal and check `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`
- If OK, install LibreOffice: `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install libreoffice`

I hope it will help you. It worked for me.

Comment: Greetings, LM is off topic here. Please post answers tested on Ubuntu or one of the official derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This cleans the cache of downloaded packages and tries to install the broken dependencies again.

Comment: sorry, but didn't work to fix the broken package update error above

Answer (score 0):

**Just**

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

**Worked for me.**

My system is:

```
18.04.1-KUbuntu 
LibreOffice 6.4.2.2 40(Build:2)
```